# How to copy file and paste its path in Vim in normal and insert mode?

Tags: vim, clipboard, paste

Ubuntu has this feature that copy a file and pasting it into a text field pastes its path in the text field. Good. But how to do to that in Vim (launched using `vim -g` after installing `vim-gtk`) both in insert (for opening the file `:e /file/path`) and normal mode?

I tried `:e` <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd> but pasted text that I had copied earlier somewhere else. I tried it on Emacs <kbd>Ctrl-y</kbd> and in the address bar of Firefox <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>, it worked as expected.

Comment: Are any of the proposed answers so far coming close to what you are asking? By the way, pasting text after `:e` is called command mode. Insert mode is when editing the buffer. So are you asking for how to paste while in command mode, insert mode, normal mode, or all of the above?

Comment: LiveWireBT's worked in normal mode. I'm looking for pasting in command mode. Insert mode would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following shortcuts:

For copying text:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

To paste:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. The paste key combination in insert mode adds `^` (seems similar to Emacs `C-q`). And in normal mode enters into visual mode.

Answer (score 1):

By `vim-gtk` do you mean `gvim`?

(Because I tried installing the `vim-gtk` package in 14.04 and when I ran `vim.gtk` from terminal it didn't launch GVIM but vim instead)

## GVIM

- To copy from GVIM to the clipboard use: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

  (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> on a QWERTZ keyboard)
- To paste from the clipborad to GVIM use: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

  (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> on a QWERTZ keyboard)

I haven't really used vim or GVIM yet, but a coworker is using it (on Windows...). <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> seems to be specific to visual commands and should work with vim specific commands like `yw`, `y$`, `10Y` and so forth.

## vim running in Gnome Terminal

To paste from clipboard enter insert mode with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave the insert mode.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> are general commands to copy and paste text from Gnome Terminal to the clipboard, but I think you already knew that.

I'm sure that real vim users would come up with more elegant solutions. As I said, I just installed GVIM and dug through the menus. (I tried using `vim` before, but always was lazy and went back to `nano`.)

Comment: I ran it with `vim -g`

Comment: The paste command works. Not sure what the one in braces does because after I typed `@ +` I had the path in the command-line (minibuffer in Emacs lingo) furthering typing `g P` appended `gp` to the path hitting `enter` there after raised the `Pattern not found` error. Question updated. I need to paste it insert mode. Thanks a lot though.

Comment: The ones in braces should be the same, but may be not as I'm using a QWERTZ keyboard. Can you look in the GVIM edit menu if your's are different?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. What are you exactly asking me to check under the edit menu? It says *paste* is bound to `"+gP`. And it doesn't state which *Keymap* is active.

Comment: No no, everything is fine. Sorry for causing this confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Vim has two registers for interacting with X text selection and clipboard. In your question you mention that you tried the `"*` register, but there is another register for yanking to and putting from the X clipboard, namely `"+`. As long as vim is built with X11 support (which the `vim-gtk` package has), both vim and gvim use these two registers for working with the X selection and clipboard buffers. Use the `"*` register if you want to paste text that has been highlighted with the mouse and use `"+` to paste text that has been copied to the clipboard from another program.

#### Paste from the clipboard in normal mode

To paste from the X clipboard into a vim buffer while in normal mode, use `"+p`, `"+P`, `"+gp`, or `"+gP` depending on whether you want the text to be inserted before or after the cursor location and where you want the cursor to end up after pasting. See [`:help put`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#put) in vim.

#### Paste from the clipboard in insert mode

If you are in insert mode in a vim buffer and want to paste the contents of the clipboard, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and `+`. This will insert the clipboard text at the cursor location and keep you in insert mode to continue entering text after what was pasted. See [`:help i_CTRL-R`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-R) in vim.

#### Paste from the clipboard in command mode

Pasting from the clipboard in command mode (while entering commands after `:`) is exactly the same as in insert mode, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> followed by `+`. So, referring to your original example of copying a file name in the system's file browser, you could open that file in vim by starting the command `:e`, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, and then `+` to paste the file name. See [`:help c_CTRL-R`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-R) in vim.

---

Vim has a large set of registers, some of which are general purpose for the user, and some of which have specific functions. For more information about Vim registers in general, see [`:help registers`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#registers) in Vim's manual. For more about the difference between the X selection and clipboard buffers, see [`:help x11-selection`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#x11-selection). And the specific uses of the `"*` and `"+` registers are described in [`:help quotestar`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html#quotestar) and [`:help quoteplus`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#quoteplus).